# onclick function with another function in input e multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In my js file, I have a Datatable where some buttons can appear under some conditions. When these button are clicked, a global variable is setted thanks a function invoked thanks onclick function.

This is an example of my actual button:

```
{ "data": "file_integrity",
                        "render" : function (data, type, full, meta) 
                        {
                            return data > 0 ? "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onclick='editName(\"" + full.name +"\");'> " +
                                    "Check! </button>" : '0';
                        }
                    }
```

Actually this works fine; the button is correctly showed or not, depending on condition, and when i click him, this function:

```
function editName(aHostName)
{

    host_name = aHostName;
};
```

correctly set this global variable: `var host_name`.

Suppose I have another global variable, this: `var type_name` and that I want transform my edit function, so to make set also this one; in other words, the function would become:

```
function editName(aTypeName, aHostName)
{
    type_name = atypeName;
    host_name = aHostName;
};
```

and suppose that i want set type name with a String that reflect the `"data"`; so, in the example above, caus we have `"data": "file_integrity"` I want set type_name with string "File Integrity". This means that the string "File Integrity" is the input for editname and this set `type_name = "File Integrity";`; the question is: what is the correct sequence escape to use on the onclick funtion, considering that is on a rendering inside data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this slightly differently - Instead of calling `onclick` and passing the arguments to the `editName` function, you can create data attributes for the values and use the datatables `rowCallBack` to bind a click event to the button.

```
"render" : function (data, type, full, meta) 
 {
    return data > 0 ? "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-typename='" + data + "' data-hostname='" + full.name + "'> " + "Check! </button>" : '0';
 }
```

Then in the datatable [rowCallBack](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) event you can bind the click event to the button which assigns the data-attribute values to your global vars:

```
'rowCallback': function (row, data, index) {
    var btn = $(row).find("button");
    btn.on('click', function (e) {
        type_name = $(e.target).data('typename');
        host_name = $(e.target).data('hostname');
    });
}
```